# winUSB error (possible .inf issue)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, winusb

I would really really appreciate some help with winUSB. 
I followed all the steps that were listed in msdn website

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450799(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540174(v=vs.85).aspx

I tried to run it on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010. Even though it compiles with no errors,  I cannot pass the function 
SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo, and it errors out (I think error #259). 
I don't know how to pass this error.

However I am not sure of the few steps in the process:

1. What does msdn talk about with "A signed catalog file for the package. This file is required to install WinUSB on x64 versions"? What is a signed catalog package? How do I set this?
2. It also talks about making some directory (For example, c:\UsbDevice) to put the .inf file in there ! But how does my VS project know that I am pointing to c:\UsbDevice, and how does it know what the name of the ".inf' file should be? what should I call the .inf file? And how to point the project to it?
3. Inside the .inf file there are two GUID numbers. I can get the Class GUID number by going to the Device Manager. But how do I set the Device Interface GUID? 
   Please help. 
   Is is possible that the error that I am getting is because I don't have one of the following items set up correctly?

Thanks,
--Rudy

Answer (score 0):

I developed an application about 2 years ago that I needed to use WinUSB, it's not fresh in my mind but looking at my code now I can see that I did use this function: SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo, but as I remember it wasn't a problem for me.

As you probably know, the WinUSB is an API of Windows for you to communicate with an usb hardware. The hardware must have it's driver already, so, you have to know the GUID of your device

Answering your steps:
1. Signed catalog is the .cat file generated from an inf, you can genarate it using inf2cat.exe, it's somwhere in your machine. This is just a step for signing your winusb driver. To sign it you will need to submit your .inf and the .cat files for the WHQL (windows hardware quality labs) http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/whql/ , this is not important at this moment, I've never signed my WinUSB driver, and it works in the x64 machines with a inelegant warning saying that my WinUSB driver might be dangerous (despite it's not!)
2. The application you are developing doens't need to know where the .inf file is, the .inf file is meant to install the WinUSB driver, the application will communicate with the driver trough the GUID number of the device after the driver is properly installed. Here is part of the code that is necessary to connect to the device after the WinUSB driver is correctly installed.

```
LPGUID _lpGuid = (LPGUID) malloc (sizeof(GUID));
HRESULT result = CLSIDFromString (L"{A54E04AD-E06A-4A03-95BB-25AACC4E6CCA}", _lpGuid);

    ...

bResult = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInfo,
                                    NULL,
                                    _lpGuid,
                                    0,
                                    &interfaceData);    //If the function succeeds
                                    //the return value is nonzero.
    // [1]
deviceInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(_lpGuid,
                 NULL, NULL,
                 DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

if (deviceInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    //lblDispStatus->Caption = "Erro 1 - deviceInfo";
    return false;
}

    // [2]
interfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
bResult = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInfo,
                                    NULL,
                                    _lpGuid,
                                    0,
                                    &interfaceData);    //If the function succeeds
                                                        //the return value is nonzero.
```

InterfaceData is passed as reference, so you will have the ability to call the next function, that is SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail

3.Who developed the driver? He must know the GUIDs you need.

All I know from WinUSB I fount at the poor WinUSB documentation, you will need tons of patiante to read all their messy information. And for your unlucky, it's not fresh in my mind right know, I would have to take a deep look at this subject to help you more.

This page seems important at the point you are, take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx